# Looking for Redirection ASP.NET User authentication and alternative to Create new user wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been having fun with ASP.NET until I arrived at the User Authentication in my journey. It's like I have hit a brick-wall.

I am not trying to re-invent the wheel, I can't even if I tried, so I decided to simply use the forms authentication and an SQL Server Database to store user password. I can use a GUID and HASH using SHA256 or SHA512, or even salting before data insertion.

However when I tried using this code I got an error that it was obsolete:
*This is just for demonstrating my use of forms authentication not a real project:*

**Code:**

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text) & 
(txtUserName.Text.Trim().Length > 1) & (txtPassword.Text.Trim().Length > 1))
{
ltrStatusMsg.Text = Database.InsertData(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, chkMemory.Checked);
}
else
{
ltrStatusMsg.Text = "InValid Login";
}
```

My question is should I simply abandoned this idea of doing my own authentication; or is there no harm using the above method? Or use the Wizard?

If Having Visual Studio Create the DB and using the Wizard is the most effective way, then I have no choice. I am simply doing a very basic web app nothing with Data about the next Alien Flight. :)

Please advise:

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [Membership.ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser(v=vs.80).aspx).

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100559/how-to-use-forms-authentication-without-login-control)

**Edit:**

It seems the problem of configuration. Your current db location might not be accessible.

Create db in SQL Server and Configure Asp.net Application Service to use it. Please go through below link that outlines how to do it.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx

Comment: I should have stated that this only occurs with .NET 4.5 and not 4.
When I run this project I get an error message because Visual Studio needs to create a database but can't because of a network location. I just need some advise as to where I should put my energy. - Thank you!

Comment: Thanks my friend! I switched to .Net4.5 and after Reading ASP.NET Unleashed and Beginning ASP.NET Security, I was able to figure this out in addition to your reference. I configured my the DB using using the aspnet_regsql.exe and then user the SQLMemberProvider.